# Excel insert data from one sheet to other in same order

Tags: excel, macros, copy-paste

I am using the below code to insert the data from one sheet to other. However, the table seems to be reversed. How do i read it from bottom up instead of top bottom

**Code:**

```
Sub InsertData()
    Dim dc As Range
    With Sheets("Open Tickets")
        For Each dc In Intersect(.Range("J:J"), .UsedRange)
            If dc.Value2 >= 14 Then
                dc.Resize(1, 1).EntireRow.Copy
                Sheets("Dashboard").Rows(6).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess:   Sheets("Dashboard").Rows(6).Insert Shift:=xlUp ?

Comment: No luck, does not work..

Comment: Why do you have to insert it in row 6? Is there a particular requirement?

Comment: Yes, i have some static text above it so need to start from there..

Comment: Yeah but that's it, no other requirement. So rows 7 onwards is ok?

Answer (score 1):

If you always insert before row 6, shifting row 6 downwards, then the first insert will be in row 6, shifting the old content of row 6 downwards. The second insert will also be in row 6, shifting the first insert downwards. The third insert will also be in row 6, shifting the second and first insert downwards and so on.

You should have a row counter. Like so:

```
Sub InsertData()
    Dim dc As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = 6
    With Sheets("Open Tickets")
        For Each dc In Intersect(.Range("J:J"), .UsedRange)
            If dc.Value2 >= 14 Then
                dc.Resize(1, 1).EntireRow.Copy
                Sheets("Dashboard").Rows(lRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                lRow = lRow + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. One more question, if i run macro everytime it creates the table everytime. Is it possible to delete the existing table copied before each macro run

Comment: You mean deleting the rows 6 till last row? `Sheets("Dashboard").Range("6:1048576").Delete`

Comment: @Arihant: Then the data that was copied from an other sheet must be detected somehow and distinguish from the data which shall stay. Are there distinctive features which they distinguish from the data which shall stay?